# How to reload app in Genymotion and Android Studio without rebooting the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I am using Android Studio 0.9.9 and Genymotion 2.3.1.

When I press run app in Android Studio, the Android Studio will allow me to choose to deploy my app in Genymotion which I usually do.

At this point, the app is running.

Let say at this point, I want to make a change in the code.

I saved the changes in Android Studio.

How do I reload my changes and redeploy the app without rebooting the Genymotion?

**EDIT**
Ultimately, just upgrade to latest stable downloads of Android Studio was the solution.

Comment: run your app again it will not reboot your Genymotion

Comment: counter is a static variable ?

Comment: counter is not static

Comment: I think you should be asking a separate question regarding the counter value. For the rest of the question, re deploying the application into the emulator will not carry over values from the previous installation unless the values were saved on files or in the SQLite database.

Comment: okay let me rephrase my question.  I want to reload the app inside the emulator. Reload being the fact that if my app has a button in activity A, and I press it, and it opens activity B, and I go back to Android Studio to type a comment, I want to reload the app and it auto starts right back at activity A. I could do this by stopping the emulator and restart the emulator and then press run on the Android Studio.  But I prefer there is a better way to do this. Right now, Android Studio does not allow me to just press run and it jumps right back to the original activity. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as eyal-lezmy mentioned you should download `Android Studio 1.0.2 Stable edition`, (you always want the latest edition, especialy if the IDE is that fresh as `Android Studio` is.

If I understood correctly you want to erase and re install your application from your emulator. To do so,In your emulator, go to `Menu`-->`Settings`-->`Apps`, then choose your application and unistall it. Then, go to `Android Studio` and `run` your applciation.

**Edit** considering your comment
 `Reload being the fact that if my app has a button in activity A, and I press it, and it opens activity B, and I go back to Android Studio to type a comment, I want to reload the app and it auto starts right back at activity A`.

If you make any change to your code, then to see in in action you must re-run the application. However, if you want your default starting activity to be `Activity B`, then you should go to your `manifest` file, remove this from Activity A code:

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

and place it inside the activity B code, where you want your application to start from.

Comment: @KimStacks my 1 was a typo I will edit (thanks for the note). The fastest way I can think of is just re-runing the project as you did `run` it in the beginning (imho I dont think there is any faster way than that).

Comment: the re-run did not appear to work the way I expected it to. I will install 1.0.2 to try

Answer (score 6):

Press F1 in Genymotion and click on "Reload JS" incase of react-native app development.

Press F2 for Android Studio emulator.

Answer (score 1):

-Turn off the emulator 
-In Genymotion Window click the settings icon infront of the device name 
-under "Android system options", check the "Show Android navigation bar"
-click ok and start the emulator

You will get the navigation bar from where you can kill the app

Answer (score 0):

I have met a similar problem in Android 2.3.7 under Genymotion. I just closed the application before starting

Comment: close what application? Genymotion or Android Studio?

Comment: Kim Stacks, close app in Genymotion

Comment: How do I close the app in Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to reload (refresh) an application on your Genymotion mobile device emulator and see your last changes in the code, you are going to do the following:

1. Go to the window of Genymotion virtual device, that you run yet;
2. Point cursor on the top bar with **ᴧ** Expo logo
3. Make left click mouse and hold it
4. Move cursor to the refresh symbol ↻ and push on it

Answer (score -1):

You actually don't really need to do nothing.
When you click on the IDE's button to build and deploy your app. Android Studio will close it, install it and then run it again including your changes.

What's happening on your side?

Btw, I really advise you to update Android Studio, since the 1.0 version, the soft is very stable and behaving really as expected.